# Looping through While read separates the string in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have json file named as test.json, I want to parse the value of id, name and not_after then put in condition to verify the not_after should not exceed before 60 days.

vi test.json

```
{
  "id" : 10001,
  "name" : "Test Client Name",
  "type" : "PKCS12",
  "provider" : "SunJSSE",
  "password" : "1111111",
  "url" : "data:application/xxxx-xxx,1234567890987",
  "entry" : [ {
    "alias" : "example.com,
    "type" : "PrivateKeyEntry",
    "algorithm" : "EC",
    "subject" : "C=CA, ST=ON, L=Toronto, O=Techonology, OU=example, CN=example.com",
    "issuer" : "C=US, O=example Lab, CN=ExampleCA",
    "not_before" : "Fri, 21 Aug 2020 19:44:26 GMT",
    "not_after" : "Sun, 21 Aug 2022 19:44:26 GMT",
    "tn_auth_list" : [ {
      "spc" : "AA001"
    } ]
  } ],
  "created_date" : "Thu, 20 Aug 2020 04:38:16 GMT"
}{
  "id" : 10002,
  "name" : "client-02",
  "type" : "PKCS12",
  "provider" : "SunJSSE",
  "password" : "1111111",
  "url" : "data:application/xxxx-xxx,1234567890987",
  "customer_id" : 12002,
  "entry" : [ {
    "alias" : "example.com",
    "type" : "PrivateKeyEntry",
    "algorithm" : "EC",
    "subject" : "C=US, ST=CA, L=San Ramon, O=Five9, OU=example, CN=example.com",
    "issuer" : "C=US, O=example Lab, CN=ExampleCA",
    "not_before" : "Tue, 2 Jun 2020 12:15:36 GMT",
    "not_after" : "Thu, 2 Jun 2022 12:15:36 GMT",
    "tn_auth_list" : [ {
      "spc" : "ZZ001"
    } ]
  } ],
  "created_date" : "Mon, 14 Dec 2020 21:42:35 GMT"
}
```

The output of jq could not be consider as one string in while read, so that condition not working properly, If i give only *.entry[].not_after* I can get the *not_after* output perfectly. Need some help that *while read* should not break the names string and it should consider the name as single string.

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.name, .entry[].not_after' | while read name expirydate; do
    echo certname=$name
    echo expiryday=$expirydate
    not_after="${expirydate}"
    echo expirydate=$not_after

    condition=$(( $(date +%s) + $((60*24*60*60)) ))
    echo condition=$condition

    not_after_in_seconds=$(date -d "$not_after" +%s)
    # echo not_after_in_seconds: $not_after_in_seconds
    # echo not_after_in_date: $(date -d @$not_after_in_seconds)

    if [ $condition -ge $not_after_in_seconds ]
    then
      echo Certificate name : $certname will be expire in 60 days, Expiration Date = $not_after
    else
      echo No issues for 60 days
     fi
done
```

output:

```
certname=Test
expiryday=Client Name
expirydate=Client Name
condition=1661241563
date: invalid date 'Client Name'
./dummy.sh: line 15: [: 1661241563: unary operator expected
No issues for 60 days
certname=Sun,
expiryday=21 Aug 2022 19:44:26 GMT
expirydate=21 Aug 2022 19:44:26 GMT
condition=1661241563
Certificate name : will be expire in 60 days, Expiration Date = 21 Aug 2022 19:44:26 GMT
certname=client-02
expiryday=
expirydate=
condition=1661241563
Certificate name : will be expire in 60 days, Expiration Date =
certname=Thu,
expiryday=2 Jun 2022 12:15:36 GMT
expirydate=2 Jun 2022 12:15:36 GMT
condition=1661241563
Certificate name : will be expire in 60 days, Expiration Date = 2 Jun 2022 12:15:36 GMT
```

Expected output:

```
Certificate name : Test Client Name will be expire in 60 days, Expiration Date = 21 Aug 2022 19:44:26 GMT
Certificate name : client-02 will be expire in 60 days, Expiration Date = 2 Jun 2022 12:15:36 GMT
```

Comment: Note that you are missing `"` in line 10 of your example data (alias), it should be `"example.com"`.

Comment: Yes I missed `"`  in my script. Adding `@sh`  at jq command resolves my issue. 
 Thank you so much @dan

Answer (score 0):

We can use `| @sh` to quote a JSON array for evaluation by the shell:

```
jq -r '[.name, .entry[].not_after ] | @sh' test.json
```

Gives:

```
'Test Client Name' 'Sun, 21 Aug 2022 19:44:26 GMT'
'client-02' 'Thu, 2 Jun 2022 12:15:36 GMT'
```

Now we have a list of four separate words. We can use `eval` to store this in a bash array.

An example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval "a=($(jq -r '[.name, .entry[].not_after ] | @sh'))"

for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i+=2)); do
    name=${a[i]} expiry=${a[i+1]}

    expiry_epoch=$(date -d "$expiry" +%s)
    now_epoch=$(date +%s)

    days_left=$(( (expiry_epoch - now_epoch) / 86400 ))

    if ((days_left == 0)); then
        echo "$name: warning: expires today"
    elif ((days_left < 0)); then
        echo "$name: EXPIRED $((days_left*-1)) days ago"
    elif ((days_left < 60)); then
        echo "$name: warning: expires in $days_left" days
    else
        echo "$name: $days_left days left"
    fi
done
```

Use like: `expiry-script < test.json`

Correctly calculating days remaining isn't always simple. This script truncates the current day (ie. 4.9 days becomes 4 days). That may be desired, but it's also wrong one hour per year, if the timezone has daylight savings time. DST causes a 23 hour day, meaning a day is truncated when it shouldn't be.

One alternative, which doesn't have this problem, is to round up or down to the nearest day:

```
printf -v days_left %.0f \
    "$(echo "scale=1; ($expiry_epoch - $now_epoch)/86400" | bc)"
```

This is a different approach. Rounding does avoid the DST issue though.